# JSF Flash cookie throws error on application restart

Tags: jsf

I am using the `Flash` in my application and when I restart my tomcat I get the following Error resulting in disabled flash.

`Jul 23, 2013 11:20:29 AM com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash$PreviousNextFlashInfoManager decode
SEVERE: JSF1094: Could not decode flash data from incoming cookie value ??o?/tv?
.  Processing will continue, but the flash is unavailable for this request.`

The workaround to this is to clear my cookies or wait until the cookie expires with the session. Is there a way that I can invalidate this? Should I invalidate the session altogether?

Answer (score 0):

This has been raised as a bug:
https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2862

Comment: Did you find an answer ?

Comment: This bug is supposed to be fixed (see above link), but I haven't tested it. Did you tried with the latest code and get the same problem?

Comment: I would suggest that you raise it again (I think that they do not reopen tickets)